# How to copy the current text line without highlighting it?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, copy-paste, text

I find it annoying that I have to highlight a given piece of text and then press <kbd>**CMD**</kbd> +<kbd>**C**</kbd> to copy it into the buffer.

I want to be able to copy text by simply pressing <kbd>**CMD**</kbd> +<kbd>**C**</kbd>, which would copy the whole line on which my cursor is placed.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific app? Most apps don’t use ctrl/c, but Cmd/c. That aside, how are you expecting any app to be able to distinguish when you want to copy a whole line, or just part of one?

Comment: sorry, i meant Cmd/c. And I want to copy a whole line by default.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you are looking for is triple-click on the line and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that highlights and copy the whole line.

On certain code editors a piece of text is copied just by highlighting it.

Comment: Why is this down voted?  It is correct and is easy to use if you have 'tap to click' set on your mouse/trackpad.