# Modify cmd+c to copy entire line

Tags: mac, shortcut

I want to modify cmd+c so that when I press it, it copies the entire line the cursor is currently placed on.

How do I accomplish this?

I want this configuration to be system-wide.

Comment: Do you want to do this system-wide or only for a specific application?

Comment: @nohilliside system-wide, edited the question

Comment: CMD+C will copy whatever is selected - including the entire line if that’s what have selected. This doesn’t just apply to text, but other content (e.g. images, etc). So, would it be fair to say that you’re looking for a shortcut to use with only text that highlights the entire line *and* copies it?

Comment: As triple-clicking selects the entire line; perhaps some macro program can be programmed to triple-click at the insertion point, then Copy, when you hit CMD-C.

Comment: [How to copy the current text line without highlighting it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372816/how-to-copy-the-current-text-line-without-highlighting-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy the current text line without highlighting it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372816/how-to-copy-the-current-text-line-without-highlighting-it)